# Trouble in implementing fixed-point numbers in C

Tags: c, decimal, fixed-point

I am trying to make a small fixed-point math library. My fixed point numbers are 32-bit, with 16 bits each for the integral and fractional parts. The trouble comes with adding fixed-point numbers and then seeing the resulting value. The function `fixed_from_parts` below takes an integral and fractional part, and emits a fixed-point number, so `fixed_from_parts(5, 2)` would equal `0000000000000101.0000000000000010`.

When adding two numbers, as seen in the `main` function below, it seems that the integral parts are added as one number, and the fractional part is added as another (5.2 + 3.9 incorrectly becomes 8.11, because 5 + 3 == 8 and 2 + 9 == 11). I think that I need to reverse the order of the bits stored in the fractional part, but I'm not quite sure how to do that. Am I overcomplicating this? How do I make addition work correctly?

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int16_t integral_t;
typedef int32_t fixed_t;

fixed_t int_to_fixed(const integral_t x) {
    return x << 16;
} 

integral_t fixed_to_int(const fixed_t x) {
    return x >> 16;
}

// shifts right (clears integral bits), and then shifts back
integral_t get_fixed_fractional(const fixed_t x) {
    return (integral_t) x << 16 >> 16;
}

// fixed_from_parts(5, 2) == 5.2
fixed_t fixed_from_parts(const integral_t integral, const integral_t fractional) {
    return int_to_fixed(integral) + fractional;
}

void print_fixed_base_2(const fixed_t x) {
    for (int i = (sizeof(fixed_t) << 3) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        putchar((x & (1 << i)) ? '1' : '0');
        if (i == sizeof(fixed_t) << 2) putchar('.');
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

void print_fixed_base_10(const fixed_t x) {
    printf("%d.%d\n", fixed_to_int(x), get_fixed_fractional(x));
}

int main(void) {
    // 5.2 + 3.9 = 9.1
    const fixed_t a = fixed_from_parts(5, 2), b = fixed_from_parts(3, 9);

    print_fixed_base_2(a);
    print_fixed_base_2(b);

    const fixed_t result = a + b;

    print_fixed_base_2(result);
    print_fixed_base_10(result); // why is the result 8.11?
}
```

Comment: You need to understand how fixed-point works. Let's use fewer bits, say 8 bits with 4 bits for the integer and 4 bits for the fraction. Then the number `0101.0010` is **not** 5.2. It *is* `5 + 2/16` which in decimal is 5.125. The bit weights (assuming unsigned numbers) are `8, 4, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625`. So `0101.0010` is `4 + 1 + 0.125 = 5.125`.

Comment: `fixed_from_parts(5, 2)` is not `5.2`, it is rather  `5 + 2/(2^16)`

Comment: You need to be more careful defining how your fixed-point format actually works.  Storing 5.1 as 0x00050001 can probably be made to work, but let's think a little:  If 5.1 is  0x00050001, does that mean 5.10 is 0x0005000a?  But 5.1 should be the same as 5.10!  What about 5.11?  Is that  0x0005000b, or something else?  And what about 5.01, or 5.001?

Comment: 16 bits can comfortably store up to 9999, so you probably want to say that the fraction is *in ten thousandths*.  So both 5.1 and 5.10 would be `(5 << 16) | 1000`, and you could represent 5.0001 as 0x50001.

Comment: But the other thing is that if you do it this way, after doing an addition, you're going to have to manually implement a *carry* from the fractional part to the integral part.  It was the lack of a carry that caused you to get the wrong answer: you had 5.2 + 3.9 wrongly coming out as 8.11 because, as you saw, 2+9=11.  After adding, you need to look at the sum and, if it corresponds to a fraction greater than 1, implement a carry into the integral part.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, here's a great article (reprinted in two different magazines): https://www.embedded.com/fixed-point-math-in-c/ https://www.eetimes.com/fixed-point-math-in-c-2/

Comment: Other (and somewhat more conventional) ways of doing this involve treating your integer, not as 16 bits of integer plus 16 bits of fraction, but rather, as a number multiplied by your fixed point.  If your fixed point is 100, you store 5.1 by multiplying it by 100 to get 510.  The *fixed point* is therefore always two places to the left, counted from the right edge.  Or you could use a binary multiplier, like 512.  In either case, addition (with carry) automatically takes care of itself, although you have to make a correction when you start multiplying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your one is not a fixed point.

Example:

```
#define MULT    (1 << 16)

#define MAKE_FIXED(d)  ((int32_t)(d * MULT))
#define MAKE_REAL(f)   (((double)(f)) / MULT)

int32_t mulf(int32_t a, int32_t b)
{
    int64_t part = (int64_t)a * b;
    return part/MULT;
}

int32_t divf(int32_t a, int32_t b)
{
    int64_t part = ((int64_t)a * MULT) / b;
    return part;
}


int main(void)
{
    int32_t num1 = MAKE_FIXED(5.2);
    int32_t num2 = MAKE_FIXED(3.9);


    printf("%f\n", MAKE_REAL(num1 + num2));
    int32_t result = mulf(num1, num2);
    printf("%f\n", MAKE_REAL(result));
    result = divf(num1,num2);
    printf("%f\n", MAKE_REAL(result));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the function `get_fixed_fractional` has undefined behavior: to get rid of the integral part, you shift it out with `<< 16` which may cause arithmetic overflow. Furthermore, the type `integral_t` is signed whereas the fractional part should be unsigned. You should just mask the high bits and return a `fixed_t`:

  ```
  // clear the integral bits
  fixed_t get_fixed_fractional(fixed_t x) { return x & 0xFFFF; }
  ```
- you print the fractional part with `%d`, but it produces misleading output: `fixed_from_parts(5, 2)` is printed as `5.2` but the value is `5.000030517578125`, which you could round as `5.00003`. The code to print a `fixed_t` should be:

  ```
  void print_fixed_base_10(const fixed_t x) {
      printf("%d.%05lld\n",
             fixed_to_int(x),
             (get_fixed_fractional(x) * 100000LL + 32768) / 65536);
  }
  ```

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int16_t integral_t;
typedef int32_t fixed_t;

fixed_t int_to_fixed(integral_t x) {
    return x << 16;
}

integral_t fixed_to_int(fixed_t x) {
    return x >> 16;
}

// clear the integral bits
integral_t get_fixed_fractional(fixed_t x) {
    return (integral_t)(x & 0xFFFF);
}

// fixed_from_parts(5, 2) == 5.2
fixed_t fixed_from_parts(integral_t integral, integral_t fractional) {
    return int_to_fixed(integral) + fractional;
}

void print_fixed_base_2(fixed_t x) {
    for (int i = 32; i-- > 0;) {
        putchar((x & ((uint32_t)1 << i)) ? '1' : '0');
        if (i == 16)
            putchar('.');
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

void print_fixed_base_10(fixed_t x) {
    printf("%d.%05lld\n",
           fixed_to_int(x),
           (get_fixed_fractional(x) * 100000LL + 32768) / 65536);
}

int main(void) {
    // 5.2 + 3.9 = 9.1 (not really)
    const fixed_t a = fixed_from_parts(5, 2), b = fixed_from_parts(3, 9);
    const fixed_t result = a + b;

    print_fixed_base_2(a);
    print_fixed_base_2(b);
    print_fixed_base_2(result);

    print_fixed_base_10(a);
    print_fixed_base_10(b);
    print_fixed_base_10(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0000000000000101.0000000000000010
0000000000000011.0000000000001001
0000000000001000.0000000000001011
5.00003
3.00014
8.00017
```

You might want to pass a third argument to `fixed_from_parts` to specify the denominator:

```
// fixed_from_parts(5, 2, 10) == 5.2
fixed_t fixed_from_parts(integral_t integral, unsigned int fractional, unsigned int denominator) {
    return int_to_fixed(integral) + (fixed_t)((fractional * 65536LL + denominator / 2) / denominator);
}
```